# Can I also use reference function for Excel on Word?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I know that at Excel =A1 at specific cell, it will display same content.
I want to utilize this fuction at MS word table. Can We use this fuction at Word(MS) program or another country program?

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can import an Excel table.

Comment: Or you can create an object "Microsoft Excel Worksheet". It'll be displayed as a table in your word document and you can edit it with Excel.
But you won't be able to apply style has if it was a Word table